# Update colours of pie chart segments to the cell fill colours

Tags: excel, vba, colors, pie-chart

I'm trying to colour my pie chart segments, according to the cells the data is drawn from, using Excel 2016.

I pinched code from a YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tm0j4dstJiI) but this is hard to read in places (1, l & i are particularly hard to differentiate) so I'm not convinced I have it right.

```
Private Sub SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Dim cht As ChartObject
Dim i As Integer
Dim vntValues As Variant
Dim s As String
Dim mySeries As Series

For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects

    For Each mySeries In cht.Chart.SeriesCollection

        If mySeries.ChartType <> xlPie Then GoTo SkipNotPie

        s = Split(mySeries.Formula, ",")(2)
        vntValues = mySeries.Values

        For i = 1 To UBound(vntValues)
            mySeries.Points(i).Interior.Color = Range(s).Cells(i).Interior.Color
        Next l
SkipNotPie:
    Next mySeries
Next cht

End Sub
```

Update: here is a snip showing the charts - I'm trying to update the chart segments to represent the cell fill colours in the second column.
[image: Table & Charts]

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. There aren't any errors showing when I open up VB. I'll try and share a picture of the graphs so I can clarify what I'm attempting to do.

Answer (score 0):

With minor adjustments, this worked fine:

```
Private Sub SheetActivate()
    Dim cht As ChartObject
    Dim i As Long
    Dim vntValues As Variant
    Dim s As String
    Dim mySeries As Series

    For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects

        For Each mySeries In cht.Chart.SeriesCollection

            If mySeries.ChartType <> xlPie Then GoTo SkipNotPie

            s = Split(mySeries.Formula, ",")(2)
            vntValues = mySeries.Values

            For i = 1 To UBound(vntValues)
                mySeries.Points(i).Interior.Color = Range(s).Cells(i).Interior.Color
            Next i
SkipNotPie:
        Next mySeries
    Next cht
End Sub
```

Make sure you don't have `Option Base 1` at the top of the module. If you do, then change

```
            s = Split(mySeries.Formula, ",")(2)
```

to

```
            s = Split(mySeries.Formula, ",")(3)
```

I haven't used `Option Base 1` since I learned to count starting at zero.